# Manhwa: Ghost of the past helps the descendant of the one who sealed him

Tags: story-identification, manga

I remember the manhwa is in color.  There's a ghost of the past helps the descendant of the one who sealed him, and there is a premise in the manhwa that there are powerful items called 'artifacts' (**I think? I don't fully remember their name**). After the MC gets out of a bar he finds a female agent who has an artifact with her and these two men are trying to get it. During the fight, the ghost possesses the MC's body and wins the fight. The MC takes the girl into his car to help her and go home.  We then find out that the MC's parents are missing, and that there's a secret lair in the house the parents bought for their son.  While looking around, he sees that the girl has awoken because he sees her through window in the bathroom. The woman then knocks him out, and takes an artifact from the vault the house has.

Comment: Since this is a word-for-word copy of your [earlier question elsewhere](https://www.reddit.com/r/manhwa/comments/oake2m/need_help_finding_a_manhwa/), is there nothing else you can remember about it?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: @J Schofield - Is the manhwa full colour, or mostly black & white?

Comment: The manhwa is in color.

Comment: Do you remember about when you read this, and about how many chapters were available at the time?

Comment: From I could remember, I read it about 5 to 6 months ago, and the manhwa had around 100 chapters.